# ActionBar with tabs - weird issue when switching tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-actionbar

I have got a weird issue with the 3 tabs of my **ActionBar** :
When i go from my second tab to the third, **onCreateView()** is not called, i like it because values in my third tab are in the same state.
Now, i will switch to the first tab and go back to the third, and now **onCreateView()** is called, and i don't want that...
Someone knows how to avoid this ? I don't understand why  there is a difference between my second and my first tab !
Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because of the [offscreenlimit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getOffscreenPageLimit()) in viewpager (I suppose it's your case).

It's set by default to one which means that view pager holds one fragment at each side of your currently visible tab in memory. (And when it's in memory it means that onCreateView() gets not called)